# How to delete all blobs except the latest one in Azure Storage Account?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, blob, azure-storage

I have added a step in the Azure DevOps pipeline to automatically take Azure MySQL DB Backup before the backend run, and store it as a blob in a storage account. I've created a lifecycle management policy in the storage account to automatically delete those blobs after 7 days of modification, for cost savings.

Is there any solution such that the latest backup will be stored for eternity and not get deleted by the lifecycle policy until another backup is there? Please suggest what can be the solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an **Azure Logic App** to do this.  It would be triggered off of the upload of the new backup file and it would list out and delete all other blobs.  A sample Logic App that works with Blobs can be seen here:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/delete-all-the-azure-storage-blob-content-before-n-days-using/ba-p/838870